# What is an Event, and has there ever been one?

Tags: android, legion-of-heroes

In Legion of Heroes, three times per day there is a "Hot Time Event". As far as I can tell, this consists of a message to your inbox with a gift (or two) attached. There is a tab on the right hand side titled "Events".

The hot time events do not appear here. But they are called "events". What constitutes an event, and has there ever been one?

I know that the Korean version of the game is much more mature, but I don't speak Korean and couldn't understand the google translate of their sites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After asking customer service, the answer to this question is: No, Hot Time is *not* an Event. Current events include the Season 2 Classic, where selected Season 2 heroes have boosted attack power and possibly hp. In general, all Events come with Event Heroes. Affected heroes will have a yellow border around their portrait with a big red and yellow E in the corner.